# html code with one or many php blocks

Tags: php, html, performance

Is it okay, performance and speed wise, to put multiple `<?php ?>` blocks in html file? I mean, does the php parser work equally fast if there are multiple php blocks? Alternative is to use just one at the start, and then write huge `echo <<<END` statements.

Example of multiple php blocks:

```
<?php 
//some code here
?>

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
<?php 
//some code also here
?>

<div>
<?php 
//some code here also
?>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example of just 1 `<?php ?>` block:

```
 <?php 
if(something-true){
echo<<<END

<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>

}else{
echo<<<END
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
END;
}    
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that answer.

Comment: no problem dude ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay, performance and speed wise, to put multiple 
>   blocks in html file?

I think it is okay. I think only those php tags are what php parser sees. HTML is just a output of php which only browsers can see . if you use few php tags in a script without using html , It won't do a difference right ? so typing PHP tags in between html won't do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, but it's better to have php files separately.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean separately? If there some other way to modify html on the fly?